# Replace TAB spaces with normal spaces in sql spool file

Tags: plsql

[image]

I'm generating a spool file using SQL with space position delimiter, but the position is not correctly set because of TAB automatically sets between columns. How do I replace these TAB's with spaces, if so how many spaces need to be replaced for single TAB.

Answer (score 1):

since you are spooling with SQL, try using replace command

```
replace('',chr(09),chr(32))
chr(09)- horizontal tab
chr(32)- space
```

Comment: No it doesn’t works like that , still there were tab spaces. But issue got resolved by writing the same code in java